# How to fetch missing month as well using SQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by

The below query fetches all data, month-wise, for a given time period and it is working fine.

```
SELECT Year(From_unixtime(time))  AS yr, 
       Month(From_unixtime(time)) AS mon, 
       Sum(totalsale)             AS sale 
FROM   orders 
WHERE  1 
       AND time BETWEEN 1561953600 AND 1577854740 
       AND user__id = 45
GROUP  BY Year(From_unixtime(time)), 
          Month(From_unixtime(time)) 
ORDER  BY time DESC
```

But this query has one limitation, it doesn't fetch that month in which data doesn't exist. E.g In the below output you can see that data doesn't exist for **Aug** and **Sep** month and that's why the query doesn't fetch that month.

```
yr      mon   sale  
2019    12    -58   
2019    11    2330.25   
2019    10    3579.27   
2019    7     2846.8099999999995
```

Now what I need is to check if no data exists for that month, it should fetch empty sale value of that month. like this

```
yr      mon   sale  
2019    12    -58   
2019    11    2330.25   
2019    10    3579.27  
2019    9    0   
2019    8    0   
2019    7     2846.8099999999995
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach here uses a *calendar* table to represent all year/month combinations:

```
SELECT
    y.year,
    m.month,
    COALESCE(SUM(o.totalsale), 0) AS totalsale
FROM
(SELECT 2017 AS year UNION SELECT 2018 UNION SELECT 2019) y
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 1 AS month UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION
 SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) m
LEFT JOIN order o
    ON y.year = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.time)) AND
       m.month = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.time)) AND
       o.time BETWEEN 1561953600 AND 1577854740
WHERE
    d.year = 2019 OR                              -- display all of 2019
    (d.year = 2018 AND m.month BETWEEN 6 AND 12)  -- and second half 2018
GROUP BY
    y.year,
    m.month;
```

Note that a possibly cleaner variant of this would be to use `DATE_FORMAT` on your dates with the format mask `%Y-%m`.  Then, you would only have to aggregate on a single column, and would only require a single calendar table.

Comment: What about the static year, is it neccessary to mention?

Comment: I don't understand what "static year" means.  Can you explain it?

Comment: You have mentioned `SELECT 2017 AS year UNION SELECT 2018 UNION SELECT 2019` in your query

Comment: The calendar table(s) need to include all dates which you want to appear in the output.  SQL is not very good at generating or creating data; it was more intended to query data which already exists.

Comment: I am still confused with 2017, 2018, 2019. Is it the default query for SQL to generated months from a year or are you creating months from the table? Hope I am able to elaborate you properly

Comment: The calendar table _is_ what generates the dates.  The whole point of the answer is that your data is missing for certain dates, so we need to bring in those dates from some other source.  A calendar table is one way to do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204772/discussion-between-jayant-rawat-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: I'm not chatting, and there isn't really much more I can say.  You should try my code, and if you still have doubts afterwards, then come back with another comment.

Comment: I have tried query and it is fetching the wrong data. If you have seen my question what I want is just the missing month with 0 value. I don't need any data, as there is not any. If any data exists for that month it will show automatically.

Comment: Define "wrong" data.  What output do you see which you don't want or expect?

Comment: Sorry, my bad I forgot to add one condition. But your query is not working. It showing me the data which I am getting already, with missing month.

Comment: Please try the minor update; I removed the `WHERE` clause and placed its logic into the join.  This could be the reason for your problem.

Comment: You may add back a `WHERE` clause restricting to a certain year(s).  I will edit my question again to show how to do this.

Comment: I have done that by replacing `(SELECT 2017 AS year UNION SELECT 2018 UNION SELECT 2019) y` with `SELECT 2019 AS year) y`

Comment: @jayantrawat More typically, you would have some large calendar table and instead would just add a `WHERE` clause to choose the date range, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: I need only six months of data from now. and your query returning me the one and half years of data

Comment: @jayantrawat I will leave it to you as homework to figure out how to restrict to the date range you want.

Comment: Hey i have one more requirement in this to fetch data week wise as well

Comment: Here is my new question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62150692/how-to-fetch-data-week-wise-along-side-month-and-year-in-single-query