# How to fetch data week wise along side month and year in single query

Tags: mysql

I have this following which fetches the data Month and Year wise

```
 SELECT
    y.year,
    m.month,
    COALESCE(SUM(o.totalsale), 0) AS totalsale
FROM
(SELECT 2017 AS year UNION SELECT 2018 UNION SELECT 2019) y
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 1 AS month UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION
 SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) m
LEFT JOIN order o
    ON y.year = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.time)) AND
       m.month = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.time)) AND
       o.time BETWEEN 1561953600 AND 1577854740
WHERE
    d.year = 2019 OR                              -- display all of 2019
    (d.year = 2018 AND m.month BETWEEN 6 AND 12)  -- and second half 2018
GROUP BY
    y.year,
    m.month;
```

I also want to fetch data Week wise within this query.

Comment: Weeks cannot be mapped into year-month... get them in separate query.

Comment: Okay Thanks, I will do it that way then.